# Accessing TCP header from tcp congestion control Linux kernel module

Tags: c, module, tcp, linux-kernel

I am working on a TCP congestion control algorithm for the Linux Kernel, which I realize as kernel module.
In the code, I  want to access the tcp header and use the following function to do so.

```
void get_hdr(struct sock *sk){ 
  struct sk_buff *skb;
  skb = skb_peek_tail(&sk->sk_receive_queue);
  if (skb != NULL)
     printk(KERN_INFO "skb address: %p", skb);
  struct tcphdr *tcp_header = tcp_hdr(skb);
  if(tcp_header != 0)
     printk(KERN_INFO "tcp_header address: %p", tcp_header);
  else
     printk(KERN_INFO "tcp_header is NULL");
}
```

I think this should basically work, since it is done  [here inside the kernel](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.36/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L467)  as well.

Hower, looking at my kern.log I see that:

```
skb address: dbd94501
tcp_header address is NULL
```

Apparently the call to [tcp_hdr(skb)](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.31/include/linux/tcp.h#L181) fails.

I have no clue why that should be. Does anybody have an inspiring hint where I should look or what I have to change in order to get the tcp header back?

Cheers,

Stefan

Comment: What do you see in `skb->transport_header`? And how are you hooking into the kernel? Netfilter?

Comment: Hello @eater Thanks for your comment. I had to test it in the lab. I found out that the pointer I provided for sk was wrong in the firstplace. With the correct one my skb_peek_tail call returns null however. I guess I have to look into it a bit deeper. Thanks anyway. I am hooking not into the kernel by the way. It is a kernel module that runs directly as kernel code.

Comment: By hooking into the kernel, what I was asking was how your kernel module was getting called by the network stack. For example, if you're module was getting called before `ip_input`, it's possible `skb->transport_header` wouldn't have been set yet. But it sounds like something else is wrong. BTW, read the comments and make sure you understand the dangers of using `skb_peek_tail()`

Answer (score 1):

At line

```
struct tcphdr *tcp_header = tcp_hdr(skb);
```

you can still have skb == NULL.

Why won't you put the whole if-section in braces?

```
void get_hdr(struct sock *sk){ 
 struct sk_buff *skb;
 skb = skb_peek_tail(&sk->sk_receive_queue);
 if (skb != NULL) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "skb address: %p", skb);
    struct tcphdr *tcp_header = tcp_hdr(skb);
    if(tcp_header != 0)
       printk(KERN_INFO "tcp_header address: %p", tcp_header);
    else
       printk(KERN_INFO "tcp_header is NULL");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be a packet with no transport_header at all.